# What's the lowest amount of disk space I need to run Windows 10 64-bit?

Tags: windows-10, virtualbox, disk-space

I want to run Windows 10 64-bit in a virtual machine and VirtualBox recommends 32Gb of disk space. This would be fine but I am on a 256Gb SSD so I dont have much to spare for things that I am only testing and playing with. Whats the smallest amount of disk space I can use to run Windows 10 64-bit?

Comment: I have a laptop with a smallish SSD too. I've run VMs off a couple of different USB3 external drives, one a 7200 RPM Touro, another a Samsung SSD.  Performance is surprisingly good in either case.

Comment: I set virtual HDD to 20GB dinamically allocate and its real size is 9.6GB (without any app).

Answer (score 4):

you need at least 16GB.
all requirements are listed here: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-10-specifications.

Comment: "32 GB for 64-bit OS"  - from the link.

Answer (score 1):

If you have over 200GB of Solid State Storage, you should be completely Fine. Most OSs themselves will take under 20GB, but if you want to have a big game or media library (such as if you are a Youtuber or other video editor) or anything you might want to look for some flash drives or external SSD. I have an Xbox One S with 500GB of onboard storage, and by dad picked up a 3TB SSD that uses USB 3.0, and though it may be a little pricey, it is well worth it. Western Digital and Kingston are good companies to look for for extra storage.

Answer (score 1):

As noted by [Taleeb](https://superuser.com/a/1216035/695930), the recommended minimum disk space is 16GB. However, there appear to be a [few extra ways](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/mniehaus/2015/09/16/windows-10-reducing-the-disk-footprint/) to further reduce your storage footprint, including removing the [recovery image](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-reduce-windows-10-footprint).

The instructions provided state the following:

- Compact OS is a command line tool, so you need to open the Start menu, do a search Command Prompt, right-click it, and select Run as administrator.
- Type COMPACT.EXE /CompactOS:always and hit Enter. The tool will begin the process, which it will take anywhere from 10-20 minutes.

Comment: Your suggestion really should be fully explained in the body of your answer

Comment: I'll adjust the response accordingly